# PHP session_regenerate_id(true) performance impact

Tags: php, session

Does PHP function `session_regenerate_id(true)` frequent usage (i mean regenaratig the session id on each page load and on each AJAX call) have bad performance impact?
And if so, does it also depend on how many variables are stored in $_SESSION array?

Comment: When you regenerate a session a new file is created, with the contents of the old one, and the old one is deleted. PHP needs to write and read a file, and these operations are slow. But why would you want to regenerate the session id for each request?

Comment: I'm trying to protect a website from session fixation attacks and this is one of the countermeasures to take, but i wanted to know how frequently i should regenerate session id without affecting performance

Comment: To the question "When should I regenerate the session?" my answer is "don't do it for every request". Do it only occasionally, after a bit 'of time or after certain actions. (i.e login)

Comment: What's a reasonable amount of requests (page loads/AJAX calls) to regenerate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be expensive, especially if you're using a custom session handler that overrides session ID creation.

By default, the overhead is:

1. A call to get the current system time.
2. Two hash table lookups to find $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
3. A 63-byte format-string generated print
4. A cryptographic hash running over the output of this sprintf
5. Reading 32 bytes of entropy from /dev/random
6. Hashing that data
7. Converting the output to a string

If you have a custom hander set with `session_set_save_handler` that provides a valid argument to `$create_sid`, this will be used instead. In that case, the overhead is completely dependent on what you've specified as your save handler.

However, if the default behavior has an appreciable performance impact for you, I'd be surprised. It's really no different behavior from if you had a bunch of requests from clients that ignored cookies.

Comment: So is it reasonable to regenarate the ID on a random base of 20-30 requests (page loads/AJAX calls) if the using default `session_set_save_handler`?

Comment: I don't think it should cause significant problems on modern hardware